# HTML5 Video centering source

Tags: css, html, video

I have a video that I will be mainly displaying on a portrait screen and I would like the video to be the full height of the screen but centered so the centre of the video is the centre of the screen. I have my current CSS and HTML below. This will display the video of 100% the height but the actual source (video) is played from the left-hand side of itself, not the centre. Is there anyway to do what I'm asking? Also, the video maybe displayed landscape and would need the same result.

**Left of this image is what im getting, right is what I want**
[image]

```
.videoContainer 
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.videoContainer video 
{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%
}

  <div class="videoContainer">
    <video width="944" height="532" controls preload="auto" poster="posterimg.jpg">
        <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="test.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="test.ogv" type="video/ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
    </video>
  </div>
```

Comment: According to your dimensions of the video tag, the video is a landscape format at the typical 16:9 aspect ratio a portrait orientation is possible but it's either going to be cropped (portions of video are cutoff) or boxed (smaller dimensions with empty space above and below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probaly mean the `object-fit` property in CSS. This will scale the video to fill the video container element, keeping its ratio intact.

You can change the *height* of the video in the snippet below. You will notice the video will scale itself to the exact *height* of its container.

**With `object-fit: cover;`**

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<video controls> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
</video>
```

**Without `object-fit: cover;`**

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video controls> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
</video>
```

You can make nice full width video's with this property. It will fill the whole container with the video. Instead of having these top and bottom bars. Which is normaly caused by the automatic scaling to its correct ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
video {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   text-align:center;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoContainer">
 <video controls> 
   <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
   <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
   <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
   <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
 </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
video {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/000/328/original/bokeh2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```